# angular 6: Template Driven creating form with json and how to handle multiple checkbox

Tags: angular

I am creating a form which is dynamically rendering the form controls using the json which can be changed. I am stuck on how I can submit the multiple checkbox value. Below is sample code.

Thanks In Advance

**TS File**

```
fields: any[] = [
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'firstName',
      label: 'First Name',
      value: '',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'lastName',
      label: 'Last Name',
      value: '',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'email',
      label: 'Email',
      value: '',
      required: true,
    },
    {
      type: 'dropdown',
      name: 'country',
      label: 'Country',
      value: 'in',
      required: true,
      options: [
        { key: 'in', label: 'India' },
        { key: 'us', label: 'USA' }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'radio',
      name: 'gender',
      label: 'Gender',
      value: 'm',
      required: true,
      options: [
        { key: 'm', label: 'Male' },
        { key: 'f', label: 'Female' }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: 'checkbox',
      name: 'hobby',
      label: 'Hobby',
      required: true,
      options: [
        { key: 'f', label: 'Fishing' },
        { key: 'c', label: 'Cooking' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit(){

  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.formData);
  }

  changeData(indexOfField, indexOfOption){

    if(this.fields[indexOfField].options[indexOfOption].checked){
      this.fields[indexOfField].options[indexOfOption].checked=false;
    }else{
      this.fields[indexOfField].options[indexOfOption].checked=true;
    }

    console.log(this.fields[indexOfField].options[indexOfOption]);
  }
```

**HTML FILE**

```
<div>
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
      <div *ngFor="let field of fields;let i=index">
        <p>{{ field.label }}</p>

        <input *ngIf="field.type=='text'" ngModel type="text" name=" 
{{field.name}}" required="{{field.required}}" >

        <select ngModel *ngIf="field.type=='dropdown'" name="{{field.name}}" required="{{field.required}}">
          <option *ngFor="let option of field.options" value="option.key">
            {{  option.label }}
          </option>
        </select>

        <div *ngIf="field.type=='radio'">
           <span *ngFor="let option of field.options">
              <input ngModel type="radio" name="{{field.name}}" [value]="option.key" required="{{field.required}}" >
              {{option.label}}
           </span> 
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="field.type=='checkbox'">
            <span *ngFor="let option of field.options;let j=index">
               <input ngModel name="{{field.name}}" [value]="option|json" 
    type="checkbox" required="{{field.required}}" (click)="changeData(i,j)" >
               {{option.label}}
            </span> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another property to the checkbox options to find which are checked as below,

```
options: [
        { key: 'f', label: 'Fishing', selected:false },
        { key: 'c', label: 'Cooking', selected:true}
      ]
```

and bind this `selected` property using `ngModel`

```
<input [(ngModel)]="option.selected" />
```

Update 1 : Based on the stackblitz

Since you are binding with `ngModel` you need not use a logic to toggle the true and false so please remove that logic and I have logged the content to see if it is getting modified or not as below

```
<div *ngIf="field.type=='checkbox'">
    <span *ngFor="let option of field.options;let j=index">
       <input  name="{{field.name}}" [(ngModel)]="option.selected" type="checkbox" required="{{field.required}}" (ngModelChange)="changeData(option,field.options)" >
       {{option.label}}
    </span> 
 </div>
```

`changeData` Function

```
changeData(currentOption,allOptions){
    console.log(currentOption);
    console.log('All options changed with ngModel',allOptions)
}
```

Note: I have used `ngModelChange` function insted of `click` to see the changes

**[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uutdgc)**

Comment: Tried but getting the following issues: 1) all checkboxs are getting selected.  2) On submit getting true only.                                                                                          email: "himanshu@test.in"
firstName: "Himanshu"
gender: "m"
hobby: true
lastName: "khurana"

Comment: Is it possible to do it without selected field. I have create stackblitz url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6verta

Comment: @HimanshuKhurana I have fixed it in the [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uutdgc) and please see if this works for you!

Comment: Thanks. But when submitting the form only getting true/false  of last modified checkbox. How can we get the selected objects in the value of form.

Comment: I mean, when we submit the form. Getting the form value object :              
{country: "us"
email: "test@india.in"
firstName: "himanshu"
gender: "f"
hobby: true
lastName: "khuana"}                                                                                                   In Hobby getting true or false of last modified checkbox checked or unchecked value.  Is it possible to get select object ie : [{key: 'c', label: 'Cooking', selected:false }]

Comment: @HimanshuKhurana I think it is possible using array of data in reactive forms